# Load Local url in iframe ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, angular8

I am trying to open a file name load.html which is saved in www/ directory from home page in src/app/home/ inside an iframe but each time I am getting an error called 'cannot match any routes .url segment'.
In ionic 3 I have achieved this functionality in the exact same way. How can I achieve this functionality in ionic 4

Answer (score 0):

I was able to load the same file by putting it in the assets folder of the src directory.
The way to access it was pretty much straight forward just like any other image or file.